# Gson deserialize polymorphic member List variable is null

Tags: java, json, polymorphism, gson, deserialization

Following is the class diagram of the problem domain. We have JSON decoded messages with different semantics which trigger different methods in the code (intialize, update) for different views.

The `Message` is deserialized fine into either `InitMessage` or `DataMessage` using the solution proposed [here](https://futurestud.io/blog/how-to-deserialize-a-list-of-polymorphic-objects-with-gson) using a `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` and registering all possible subtypes. However, the `DataMessage.value` list is empty (not deserialized). The problem is the nested polymorphic member in `DataMessage`.

[image: Class diagram of the problem domain]

The adapter factories:

```
RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<Message> messageAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
     .of(Message.class, "MESSAGE_TYPE")
     .registerSubtype(InitializationMessage.class, "INIT")
     .registerSubtype(DataMessage.class, "DATA");

RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory<DataValue> dataAdapterFactory = RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory
    .of(DataValue.class, "NAME")
    .registerSubtype(DataValueA.class, "A")
    .registerSubtype(DataValueB.class, "B")
    .registerSubtype(DataValueC.class, "C");
```

The creation of the message:

```
TypeToken<Message> typeToken = new TypeToken<Message>() {};
Message msg = gson.fromJson(json, typeToken.getType());
```

DataMessage class:

```
public class DataMessage extends Message {

  private List<DataValue> value;

  public List<DataValue> getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(List<DataValue> value) {
    this.value= value;
  }
}
```

DataValueA class:

```
public class DataValueA extends DataValue {

  private Map<String, Float> value;

  public float getValue(String location) {
    return value.get(location);
  }
}
```

The corresponding JSON:

```
{
    "MESSAGE_TYPE" : "DATA",
    "VALUE" : [
    {
        "NAME"  : "C",
        "VALUE" : 1.3
    },
    {
        "NAME" : "A",
        "VALUE" : {
            "FL" : 18.4,
            "FR" : 18.4,
            "RL" : 18.4,
            "RR" : 18.4
        }
    }]
}
```

I want the `DataValue` be deserialized into their respective subclass (`DataValueA` ...).

Comment: Writing a `JsonDeserializer` for `Message` which creates the correct subclasses and delegates further deserialization via `context.<DataValue>deserialize(dataObject, DataValue.class)` gives me the ability to deserialize polymorphic message with the polymorphic data. However, I completely lose the gains in readable and maintainable code of the data binding provided with `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution is to use the `GsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter` method to register custom `JsonDeserializer`. The way is to use a field in the message to define which subclass will be created (just like with `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` which is not shipped by default and lives in `gson-extra`).

The deserializer will be registered for each abstract superclass.

```
gson = new GsonBuilder()
  .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
  .registerTypeAdapter(Message.class, new MessageAdapter())
  .registerTypeAdapter(DataValue.class, new DataValueAdapter())
  .create();
```

Given the field to distinguish subtypes is named *NAME* you can define the deserialize function as following. There is a mapping from the content of the field to the respective subclass.

```
public class DataValueAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<DataValue> {
  private final static Map<String, Class<?>> FieldToClass;

  static {
    FieldToClass = new HashMap<>();
    FieldToClass.put("PERFORMANCE", PerformanceDataValue.class);
    FieldToClass.put("TIRE_SLIP", TireSlipDataValue.class);
  }

  @Override
  public DataValue deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                               JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    JsonObject jsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
    String dataType = jsonObject.get("NAME").getAsString();
    return context.deserialize(json, FieldToClass.get(dataType));
  }
}
```

In order to make the reflective deserializer (which will be used for the subclasses as long as you are okay with the standard deserializer) work the subclasses need to state `@SerializedName` at the properties. Without it did not work for me.